# PROXY with rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have this URL:
http://rss.tipinoncomuni.it/parks/news/dettaglio.php?id=26699

and i want to rewrite it with this Virtual host, translating to

http://www.parks.it//news/dettaglio.php?id=26699:

**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaste@tipinoncomuni.it
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ServerName rss.tipinoncomuni.it
  ProxyRequests On
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^parks/(.*) http://www.parks.it/$1 [L,P,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

**

The response from server is always:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /parks/news/dettaglio.php was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at rss.tipinoncomuni.it Port 80

This is the rewite log:

> 88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303d9e0a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^sole/(.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303d9e0a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/alfresco.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303d9e0a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/share.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303d9e0a0/initial] (1)
>   pass through /parks/news/dettaglio.php
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4301b990a0/initial] (2)
>   init rewrite engine with requested uri /parks/news/dettaglio.php
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4301b990a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^sole/(.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4301b990a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/alfresco.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4301b990a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/share.*)' to uri '/parks/news/dettaglio.php'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4301b990a0/initial] (1)
>   pass through /parks/news/dettaglio.php
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303da00a0/initial] (2)
>   init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303da00a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^sole/(.*)' to uri '/favicon.ico'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303da00a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/alfresco.*)' to uri '/favicon.ico'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303da00a0/initial] (3)
>   applying pattern '^(/share.*)' to uri '/favicon.ico'
>   88.57.240.67 - - [11/Jun/2014:07:43:48 +0200] [rss.tipinoncomuni.it/sid#7f43068a59b0][rid#7f4303da00a0/initial] (1)
>   pass through /favicon.ico